# Hadoop Web Interface <ip_address>:50070 is not working

Tags: hadoop, centos

I have established a single node hadoop cluster on Cent OS 7. It is successfully installed and all the daemons are up.

My challenge is when I go to web interface like `***IP_Address:50070***` it is not showing up anything. Please suggest how do I resolve it.

**Things I tried:**

- Reconfigured properties, formatted HDFS and restarted all the daemons.

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Update the question

Comment: Do another Hadoop web interfaces work? For example, YARN web gui on host IP_Address:8088

Comment: @ Manjunath - once I give URL, it tries connecting and quits by giving This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error

Comment: @ maxteneff - no. 8088 doesnt work